# Limit the amount of oldfiles in Vim and Neovim

Tags: neovim, viminfo, shada

As simple as the title stated. Suppose I only want to keep the `n` (say 20) latest files, and the older ones be deleted.

How may I configure that?

Comment: Do you want that `:browse oldfiles` list only 20 files instead of 50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Vim or gVim users to make sure `:browse oldfiles` list maximum 20 files make sure that `viminfo`starts with `'20`.

You can achieve that by have the following line in your `.vimrc` file:

`set viminfo='20,<50,s10,h`

For Neovim users the setting to change is `shada`:

`set shada=!,'20,<50,s10,h`

Remark: I suggest you to check the current value of `viminfo` and amend it to have it correct (`:set viminfo?`)

Here is another question on stackoverflow about the same kind of problem: [How to display fixed number of entries in Vim's browse oldfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159618/how-to-display-fixed-number-of-entries-in-vims-browse-oldfiles)

Answer (score 2):

A more comprehensive Neovim / Lua version of the above accepted answer:

1. You can check the current value of the `shada` option with:

   ```lua
   :lua print(vim.opt.shada._value)
   ```
2. Set `shada` opt in `init.lua` / lua config with:

   ```lua
   vim.opt.shada = "!,'20,f1,<50,s10,h" -- default value as of Neovim 0.10
   ```
3. For more info on building up your own custom `vim.opt.shada` string value:

   - [`:h 21.3`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_21.html#21.3) covers examples of session state and
     suspension using shada.
   - [`:h 'shada'`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27shada%27) is the full reference for `shada` string (note the single quotes, which specifies we want the options reference page instead of the first result).
     options.
   - [`:h shada-file`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#shada-file) has general info about how the shada file works.
4. The ShaDa file is stored under `$XDG_STATE_HOME/nvim/shada` (default: `~/.local/state/nvim/shada`). If it becomes corrupted, you can safely delete this directory and re-launch Neovim, but ***you will lose your history for marks, search, commands, oldfiles, etc***.